# Is it possible to revert a particular line in a file when using SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, rapidsvn

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project and I have made lot of changes on a particular file.

Now I want to revert changes in some of the lines in that file.

Is it possible to revert those lines one by one in SVN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible by Subversion commands. You need an external diff tool, such as beyond compare or gvimdiff or others. IDEs also have this option. For example Eclipse and IntelliJ for Java, Pycharm for Python have this feature.

I don't what IDE you use for Ruby on Rails, if it's any decent it should have this feature. 
You could try [IntelliJ community edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/), it seems to have a [plugin for Ruby on Rails](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/ruby_rails.html). Even without the Ruby on Rails integration, you should be able to open the **Compare with Latest Repository Version** menu, see the two versions side by side and easily select the changes to keep or undo.

Comment: @janos : I am using Sublime Text 3

Comment: @rahulv there is no such feature in Sublime Text 3 or its SVN integration plug-in

Comment: Then I should try IntelliJ community edition :) Thanks @bahrep